# Is it possible to represent the base space by a set of $n$ points in Bernouilli exp?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Just a technical question.

When tossing a coin $n$ times (it's called a Bernouilli experiment I think), it is mathematically wrong to say the base space $\Omega$ is made of $n$ points, isn't it?

If $X_i$ are the iid variables corresponding to each $i$ experiment, and if for example $X_1$ result is "heads" (and the constant Bernouilli probability is $0,8$). Then, $\mathbb P(X_1="heads")=\mathbb P(X_1^{-1}("heads"))=\mathbb p(\{1\})$

Assuming that all the coins are "heads", we get $$\forall i\leq n,\mathbb P(X_i="heads") = \mathbb p(\{i\}) $$

By definition, $\mathbb P(X_i="heads")=0,8$

So when we sum up all the $\mathbb P(X_i="heads")$, we get

$$\sum {\mathbb p(\{i\}) } = n\times0,8$$

which is not equal to $1$.

Therefore the $(\Omega , \mathbb p)$ space is not a probability space.

Comment: $\Omega$ has $2^n$ points, not $n$ points. But your argument doesn't make sense to me. Why should the sum of probability of each coin being heads equal one?

Comment: $\sum \mathbb p(\{i\})$ must be equal to one because $(\Omega, \mathbb p)$ is a probability space. I have showed that this sum $\sum \mathbb p(\{i\})$ over the integers until $n$ is equal to the probability of each coin being heads

Comment: $X_i$ being heads is an *event*, not an outcome. The sum of all probabilities of *outcomes* needs to be one. The outcomes here are the possible sequences of coin flips, of which there are $2^n$. An outcome has probability $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, where $k$ is the total number of heads and $p$ is the probability of heads.